# ModelForm with ImageFields, not clearing properly if validation error

Tags: django, modelform

First the code.
The ModelForm (im1 and im2 are models.ImageField):

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    checkme = forms.BooleanField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('im1', 'im2')
```

The view:

```
def test(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    form = TestForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TestForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form':form})
```

The template:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problems:

If im1 contains a valid image, and I check the clear checkbox next to it but don't check checkme and submit, the form comes back with an error saying that checkme is required.  Although the form returns with the error, it appears as if im1 has been cleared.  In reality it has not because if I reload the form im1 shows back up with its file and clear checkbox.

My question is how can I fix this?  Is it something I am doing or is this something to do with django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is acting exactly as it should.

If the request is a POST request, then your form is bound to the data from `request.POST` and `request.FILES`. `instance=profile` is simply telling the form what particular object to save to if all validation passes. Even if your form isn't valid, it's still bound to the data with the cleared image, and that's what you're passing to `render()`.

Firstly, you shouldn't be creating the first bound form if the request method is POST:

```
def test(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TestForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = TestForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form':form})
```

Secondly, why do you want your user to do the same exact action twice if they did indeed want to delete an image but simply missed another checkbox?

If you really need Django to act this way, I would do one of two things. Either create a bound form from an instance of UserProfile and pass both the non-valid form and the newly created form to the template and use the non-valid form for displaying the errors and the other one for displaying the rest of the form:

```
def test(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    if request.method == "POST":
        errors_form = TestForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if errors_form.is_valid():
            errors_form.save()
            form = errors_form
        else:
            form = TestForm(instance=profile)
            return render(request, 'test.html', {'form':form, 'errors_form': errors_form})
    else:
        form = TestForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form':form})
```

OR I'd do the same thing but save the errors from the non-valid form to the newly created form so you don't end up with `renders()` all over the place:

```
def test(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    if request.method == "POST":
        errors_form = TestForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if errors_form.is_valid():
            errors_form.save()
            form = errors_form
        else:
            form = TestForm(instance=profile)
            #this is left up to you to implement, but you'd do something like
            #form.errors = errors_form.errors
            #and also iterate through every form attribute.errors and assign it to
            #errors_form attribute.errors etc...
    else:
        form = TestForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form':form})
```

Both aren't very elegant solutions and I'm not positive the second one will even work as expected without some more hacks since I'm not completely familiar with the Django Forms implementation.

I don't see that doing this is worth it. As I stated before, you're just creating more work for your user...

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll try some of that out, it looks promising.  I am making the user do the exact same action twice because this was a simplified test case.  In the real case the images are profile pictures and a person has to check a box that says they acknowledge the pictures will be made public on the site.  Another scenario that produces the same result is if you have no checkme box, but check clear for im1 and give im2 a non image.  The form is returned with im2 errors and im1 looking as if it was cleared. That's what I want to avoid, im1 or 2 looking cleared if they weren't.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now. You need to remember you can look at the contents of the request.POST and request.FILES dicts. You can check if "clear" is checked and if it is you can delete the image manually so if they have form errors and refresh the page it is indeed gone forever instead of showing up again.